# printer canon ip7250 drivers/pint problems

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, canon

I get my self a canon ip7250 printer.
It prints his first test page. all fine.

I download drivers from canon web-page and when I try ./install.sh I got this:

```
./install.sh 
==================================================

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver
Version 3.80
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2012
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-common_3.80-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cnijfilter-common.
(Reading database ... 245973 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-common_3.80-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cnijfilter-common (3.80-1) ...
Setting up cnijfilter-common (3.80-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-ip7200series_3.80-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cnijfilter-ip7200series.
(Reading database ... 245991 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-ip7200series_3.80-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cnijfilter-ip7200series (3.80-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-ip7200series:
 cnijfilter-ip7200series depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.8rel); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-ip7200series depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-ip7200series (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cnijfilter-ip7200series
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-ip7200series
(Reading database ... 246181 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-ip7200series (3.80-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-ip7200series (3.80-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-common
(Reading database ... 245990 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-common (3.80-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-common (3.80-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Those dpkg/errors ? Is install ok or not.
Any word of wisdom ?

Answer (score 0):

> Package libtiff4 is not installed.

You need libtiff4 ..... so go here https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libtiff4 to the debian repository and scroll down the page to the list and you likely will need the amd64 version for a 64bit ubuntu; install that and re-run the ./install.sh script and all should be well